# How to pass value of more than one variable in jsp?

Tags: java, jsp

I want to pass values of two variables when a link is clicked to another page I am using query parameter but I am only able to send one variable through it. I know about session.setAttribute() but don't know how can I use it based upon links...Foreg:

```
<a href="Search.jsp?item=<%=search%><%session.setAttribute("val",value1);%>" class="classname" style=" margin-top:20px;margin-left:800px;"><p> < </p></a>
            <a href="Search.jsp?item=<%=search%><%session.setAttribute("val",value);%>" class="classname1" > > </a>
```

This is my code I know its wrong..I just want is If I click on first link than value1 should be passed and If I click on 2nd link value should be passed.P.S.:I have already passes search variable through query parameter but now If I try to pass second parameter through session only the final value i.e second initialized value only counts? what to do?
EDIT:
suppose my code is this:

```
 <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" action="Search.jsp" method="get">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search..." name="search">
```

Here one variable search is passes through form How can I pass another variable value?should it be like:

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-right" action="Search.jsp?item1=<%=value%>" method="get">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search..." name="search">
```

Comment: Parameters are passed from client to server; attributes are server-side variables, scoped to a session, request or page http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16175861/servlet-parameters-vs-attributes

Comment: You also really, really should use expression language instead of scriptlets http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files/3180202#3180202

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can send multiple parameters like,

```
href="Search.jsp?item=<%=search%>&item2=value2&item3=value3.."
```

Also to add `<%session.setAttribute("val",value1);%>` will be executed at server side irrespective of the click of the hyperlink.

For the form you can add another input parameter in the form,

`<input type="text" name="item1" value="<%=value%>">`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add some separator in between two values e.g.#

And while reading at server side you can split those values based on that separator

Comment: You mean that I should concatenate the value of two variables and then split them in next page?

Comment: Yes.Correct. Also you can separate different parameters like Subir suggested;

Answer (score 0):

You may try using this example to send multiple values:

```
<a href="same.jsp?item=cap&item=pen&item=ball">With same name</a>
<a href="diff.jsp?gender=male&fname=Adman&lname=Smith">With diff name</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Separate the two values by using `&`:

```
<a href="Search.jsp?item=<%=search%>&item2=<%=value2%>">
```

On your `search.jsp` fetch values as :

```
request.getParameter("item");
request.getParameter("item2");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `session.getAttribute` in the place where you are calling `session.setAttribute` and session.setAttribute should be called in controller or in the jsp before the link tag to set the value. Please separate values like `Search.jsp?item1=value1&item2=value2`